# Upper bounds on $\frac{\prod_{i<j}(\sinh|x_i-x_j| \sinh|y_i-y_j|)}{\prod_{1\leq i,j\leq n} \sinh |x_i-y_j|}$

Tags: inequality, upper-lower-bounds

For $\mathbf x=(x_1,\ldots, x_n), \mathbf y=(y_1,\ldots, y_n) \in \mathbb R^n$, I am interested in the function
$$F(\mathbf x, \mathbf y) = \frac{\prod_{i<j}(\sinh|x_i-x_j| \sinh|y_i-y_j|)}{\prod_{1\leq i,j\leq n} \sinh |x_i-y_j|}.$$

Note that $F$ is divergent if $x_i=y_j$ for some $i,j$. Hence, we fix $\delta>0$ and restrict the domain of $F$ to $|x_i-y_j|>\delta$ for all $1\leq i,j\leq n$.

**Question**: What is the upper bound of $F$ on this restricted domain? (Furthermore, it would be better if one has some decay estimates on $F$.)

Remarks.

1. We may assume that $x_1\leq\cdots \leq x_n$ and $y_1\leq \cdots \leq y_n$.
2. I think $F$ should be bounded by the following heuristic argument. We have to consider the behavior of $F$ for large $x_i$ and $y_j$. Then, approximating $\sinh |x| \approx e^{|x|}$, we obtain
   $$F(\mathbf x, \mathbf y) \approx \exp\left( \sum_{i<j} (|x_i-x_j|+|y_i-y_j|) - \sum_{i,j} |x_i-y_j|\right).$$
   However, by my previous question [$2\sum_{i,j} |x_i-y_j| \geq \sum_{i,j} (|x_i-x_j| + |y_i-y_j|)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4225728/2-sum-i-j-x-i-y-j-geq-sum-i-j-x-i-x-j-y-i-y-j), The RHS is $\leq 1$.

Actually, examining the results in my previous question, we have at least
$$\sum_{i<j} (|x_i-x_j|+|y_i-y_j|) - \sum_{i,j} |x_i-y_j| \leq -\sum_i |x_i-y_i|.$$
Hence, one may expect the exponential decay estimate on $F$, which is much better than $\leq 1$ estimate. However, I did not find a rigorous way to justify on the part $\sinh |x| \approx e^{|x|}$.

Any help on this question (finding $\sup F$, or finding rigorous decay estimates) would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure it helps but for $x,y>0$ $|\cosh(x)-\cosh(y)|\geq |x-y|\sqrt{\sinh(x)\sinh(y)}$ attributed to Van der Corput !